# Firebase and Google Map

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everytime i am setting a Marker and click the Button to send the distance to Firebase, my Google Map refreshes.

Here is the Activity, i may not be the best Code, but i am just learning.

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

double latitude=38.9071923, longitude=-77.0368707;
double end_latitude, end_longitude;
Button calcbtn;
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

    calcbtn = findViewById(R.id.calcbtn);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

    calcbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float results[] = new float[10];
            Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, end_latitude, end_longitude, results);
            Marker destination = mMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Washington").snippet("Abstand: " + results[0] / 1000 + "Km!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
            destination.showInfoWindow();

            mDatabase.child(username).child("Map").child("Score").setValue(results[0] / 1000);
            return;
       }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(1.0f);
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(5.0f);

    MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(Map.this, R.raw.style_jason);
    mMap.setMapStyle(style);

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mMap.clear();
            Marker user_input = mMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng));
            end_latitude = user_input.getPosition().latitude;
            end_longitude = user_input.getPosition().longitude;
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is working as intendet, but the Map refreshes on Button click, like i would have just started the activity. All other Firebase implementations are working just fine.

Comment: Did you tried removing the return: statment that you just put in your click listener ? i mean, i think that is causing the problem, btw, what is returning ?

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed it down to the AddValueEventlistener in the previous Activity. It starts this Activity once a value is changed in Firebase.

So the previous AddValueventlistener is still running und my next Activity, but i dont know how to stop that.

//Edit: The new Activity is started with an Intend, finishing the Activity via finish() does not work.